# How would you go about this guy's fur?

Tags: modeling, particles, sculpting, geometry, hair

I'm sculpting this dragon and, so far am pretty happy with how it's turning out. However, I am not sure how I should go about modeling his fur. The target platform is the unreal engine 4 but for now I am just trying to get a nice model before retopology.
[image: Dargon]

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to create a group of mesh hair objects, and then use a particle system in Blender to place and arrange them as needed.

Then before importing into Unreal Engine, you'll have to apply the particle modifier and convert the hairs into mesh objects.

Comment: Particle system looks promising. How would I go about UV mapping and texturing the hair's once they have been converted to a mesh? Since Unreal does not play that well with blender, I need to make the materials after it's exported where I wouldn't have particle data.

Comment: Well, you should be able to UV unwrap the source hair mesh object. If you wanted to texture across a group of particle hairs, you'd probably have to apply the modifier and then group them into a single mesh object, which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I ended up doing the following:

- Create a particle system for the hair.
- Using particle edit, cut and comb the hair.
- Convert the particle to a mesh using the convert button in the modifiers menu.
- Convert that mesh to a curve.
- Bevel the curve with a simple shape (I used a triangle)
- Convert that curve back to a mesh.
- Unwrap the hairs using smart UV project. This lays all the hairs out side by side.
- Create texture for hairs.

I don't know if this is going to work with retopology but for now it looks OK though i'm a little sad I don't have that much control over the color.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a UV map on the hair, you can make the hair texture desaturated and make it any color you want by using a color overlay, or you can use the UV with a gradient texture to control procedural colors. I'm not sure but I believe that you can convert a gradient on a UV to weight and use a weight map to color your hairs as well. You have many options when it comes to color control over your object.